# Page number is not working in onScroll view in android nested scroller view

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add pagination to my code. As the first step, I am trying to fetch only 3 records for page = 1. When scrolling the page, I am trying to increase the page number using onScroll() method. But when I am scrolling page count is not increased. Why?

This is the code how I call onScroll method inside the onCreate method of my activity.

```
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.taskList);
        loadingPB = findViewById(R.id.idPBLoading);
        nestedSV = findViewById(R.id.idNestedSV);
        page = 1;


        nestedSV.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                // on scroll change we are checking when users scroll as bottom.
                if (scrollY == v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight()) {
                    // in this method we are incrementing page number,
                    // making progress bar visible and calling get data method.
                    page++;
                    loadingPB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
```

This is how I fetch data from database.

```
dailyTaskViewModel.getAllTaskTemplatesByStatus(status).observe(this, new Observer<List<TaskTemplateWithTasks>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(List<TaskTemplateWithTasks> templateWithTasks) {
                    taskCount = templateWithTasks.size();
                    if(templateWithTasks.size() == 0){
                        messageText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    else{
                        messageText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    if (page == 1 && templateWithTasks.size() > 3) {
                        List<TaskTemplateWithTasks> limitedList = templateWithTasks.subList(0, 3); // Get the first 3 elements
                        dailyTaskListAdapter.setTaskTemplates(new ArrayList<>(limitedList));
                    } else {
                        dailyTaskListAdapter.setTaskTemplates(templateWithTasks);
                    }
                    dailyTaskListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    EditText search = findViewById(R.id.search);
                    search.setText("");
                    startAdapterFilter(searchText);

                }
            });
```

This is activity.xml code.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/idNestedSV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".view.activity.dailyTask.DailyTaskListActivity">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/single_padding"
                android:background="@drawable/outline"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="@dimen/content_padding">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">


                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/taskList"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
                        tools:context=".view.activity.dailyTask.DailyTaskListActivity"
                        tools:listitem="@layout/task_item" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/message_text"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:text="@string/can_t_find_records"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/idPBLoading"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </RelativeLayout>



            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake. You add scroll listener to NestedScrollView, it should be add with RecyclerView.

Try this

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
                //Calling the method getdata again
                page++;
                loadingPB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```

You can check this [answare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45908930/android-recyclerview-adding-pagination)